# Oracle Trigger Performance is to slow

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Given the following trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_MY_TRG_NAME
    AFTER UPDATE OF COL_A, COL_B, COL_C ON T_MY_TABLE_Y
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE T_MY_TABLE_X X
        SET 
        X.COL_A = :NEW.COL_A,
        X.COL_B = :NEW.COL_B,
        X.COL_C = :NEW.COL_C
        WHERE
            X.ID = :NEW.ID;
END;
```

... and given 2 million existing records in T_MY_TABLE_Y.

**Problem**:
if my app is changing all of the 2 mio records (e.g. COL_A), then without the trigger it runs 2-3 minutes, but with the trigger it took 40min.

**Question**:
are there some alternative approaches that I could try?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thx, true

Comment: How are you updating 2 million records? Just one statement? 2 million statements in a single transaction? 2 milion statements with 2 million transactions?

Comment: Why do you have these copies of the columns in `T_MY_TABLE_X`? You probably shouldn't store them there but join them from `T_MY_TABLE_Y` when you query `T_MY_TABLE_X` (and they are really needed in that query).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to update `T_MY_TABLE_X` in a single statement, without forcing a trigger to fire for each of 2 million rows and (probably) perform context switching.

So: as you update `T_MY_TABLE_Y`, reuse the same `UPDATE` for `T_MY_TABLE_X` (with some modifications, if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might benefit to decrease the load for DML by splitting into three parts so as to update for each individual columns :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_MY_TRG_NAME
    AFTER UPDATE OF COL_A, COL_B, COL_C ON T_MY_TABLE_Y
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :NEW.COL_A != :OLD.COL_A THEN
    UPDATE T_MY_TABLE_X SET COL_A = :NEW.COL_A WHERE ID = :NEW.ID;
   END IF;

   IF :NEW.COL_B != :OLD.COL_B THEN
    UPDATE T_MY_TABLE_X SET COL_B = :NEW.COL_B WHERE ID = :NEW.ID;
   END IF;

   IF :NEW.COL_C != :OLD.COL_C THEN
    UPDATE T_MY_TABLE_X SET COL_C = :NEW.COL_C WHERE ID = :NEW.ID;
   END IF;

END;
```

This way, Update might not incur every column for each occurence.

Moreover, be sure `T_MY_TABLE_X.ID` has index on it, preferably Unique Index.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the time to write the code out, but an outline approach I can suggest trying is to create a package with a `ARRAY` of a `RECORD` of `ID`, `COL_A`, `COL_B` and  `COL_C`.

The `BEFORE` statement trigger should instantiate and initialise the package and the array within, e.g.:

`the_package.pr_init`

The `ROW LEVEL` trigger should simply write the :NEW.ID, :NEW.COL_A, :NEW.COL_B, :NEW.COL_C to the array within the package, e.g:

`the_package.pr_save (  :NEW.ID, :NEW.COL_A, :NEW.COL_B, :NEW.COL_C )`

The `AFTER` statement trigger should then issue a `BULK UPDATE` on the driving off the array within the package, and clear out the `ARRAY`, eg:

`the_package.pr_do_update`.

The benefit of this approach is you only execute ONE additional UPDATE statement regardless of how many rows.

The solution is also contained with in a single package, albeit splayed across 3 triggers, though the trigger code itself will be much simplified.